# Perforce client AND server no longer connecting, 127.0.0.1:1666 refusing all connections on server, even local connections

Tags: linux-networking, port-forwarding, ubuntu-18.04, localhost, perforce

I have a server running Ubuntu server 18.04, and it's the catch-all local server - hosts a samba share, media server, and a Perforce server.  I connect to that depot via a local network IP (ssl:192.x.x.x:1666).  Everything was working great until...

...I also tried to add a wiki.js install to it.  There was a lot of package and config thrashing.  Apache got removed, wiki.js / mongodb / mariadb / postgresql all got thrown around and deleted more than once, and nginx got installed and torn out many times.

Here's why - (context for what I was up to that *probably* caused this):

I have DNS filtering for the whole network via PiHole and with that, I created local DNS names & CNAME entries for the various processes on that Ubuntu server.  The idea was I could point a client machine elsewhere in the network to, say, "perforce.RackServer.net" instead of "192.168.0.x:1666" and get the same result with some reverse proxy'ing by nginx.  We were trying to make addressing human-readable instead of everyone having to ask me for IPs and port numbers for everything.

I did **not** have success setting up nginx.  It's uninstalled now.  That's fine - I'll come back to it later.  Here's the problem.

Somewhere in all that, something with the network configuration (the machine has eth0 and eth1) got whacked, and now when I try
`#sudo systemctl start helix-p4dctl.service`

I get

`Job for helix-p4dctl.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`
`See "systemctl status helix-p4dctl.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

A systemctl status check of that gives me:

`Jun 20 14:10:07 RackServer p4dctl[4186]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.`
                                               `connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused`
`Jun 20 14:10:07 RackServer p4dctl[4188]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.`
                                               `connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused`
`Jun 20 14:10:07 RackServer p4dctl[4189]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.`
                                               `connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused`
`Jun 20 14:10:07 RackServer p4dctl[4190]: error:         Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.`
                                               `connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer p4dctl[4181]: error:         'PerforceServer' p4d: '/opt/perforce/sbin/p4d' exited with status 255.`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer p4dctl[4181]: Started 0 services.`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer p4dctl[4181]: error:         Not all services started successfully.`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer systemd[1]: helix-p4dctl.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer systemd[1]: helix-p4dctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`
`Jun 20 14:10:08 RackServer systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts all Perforce services.`

That's similar to the error I now get trying to connect remotely with the p4v visual client: 
`Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.`
`connect: 192.168.0.117:1666: Connection refused`

Checking the P4PORT environment variable on the server gives me:

...nothing.  It SHOULD be ssl:1666 or just 1666.  It used to be, until now.  So if I set that to what it should be with

`export $P4PORT=ssl:1666`

and then go try to start the service, I get the same error as the first time.

Let's check the actual connection...

`admin@RackServer:~$ ping 192.168.0.117`
`PING 192.168.0.117 (192.168.0.117) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from 192.168.0.117: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms`
`64 bytes from 192.168.0.117: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms`
`64 bytes from 192.168.0.117: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms`

Same with:
`admin@RackServer:~$ ping 127.0.0.1`
`PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms`
`64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms`
`64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms`

And:
`admin@RackServer:~$ ping localhost`
`PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms`
`64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms`
`64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.014 ms`

However, nmap doesn't show 1666 open...
`21/tcp   open  ftp`
`22/tcp   open  ssh`
`25/tcp   open  smtp`
`139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn`
`445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds`
`631/tcp  open  ipp`
`3306/tcp open  mysql`
`3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server`

Here's the ifconfig, just for reference.
`eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500`
        `inet 192.168.0.117  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255`
        `inet6 fe80::da16:9fa8:aff2:2aef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>`
        `ether 00:04:23:d3:d0:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)`
        `RX packets 33063  bytes 2652752 (2.6 MB)`
        `RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0`
        `TX packets 1872  bytes 269690 (269.6 KB)`
        `TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`
        `device interrupt 18  memory 0xb8820000-b8840000`

`eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500`
        `inet 192.168.0.116  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255`
        `inet6 fe80::659f:d321:8607:cc5f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>`
        `ether 00:04:23:d3:d0:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)`
        `RX packets 31082  bytes 2047269 (2.0 MB)`
        `RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0`
        `TX packets 531  bytes 41557 (41.5 KB)`
        `TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`
       `device interrupt 19  memory 0xb8800000-b8820000`

`lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536`
        `inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0`
        `inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>`
        `loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)`
        `RX packets 5185  bytes 278583 (278.5 KB)`
        `RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0`
        `TX packets 5185  bytes 278583 (278.5 KB)`
        `TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

I'm not actually a networking guy by trade - and I'm still learning *nix - so I'm in way over my head, and I **have** to get that Perforce depot back online.  Everything is there, the machine is just suddenly refusing to take connections - remote OR local - on 1666 for whatever reason.  All the other services that have been working correctly are either still working or back to working.  It's just this one.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved, finally.

This Perforce installation was a release from 2021, p4d/2021.2/LINUX26X86_64/2264565 (I found this going through the logs).  At some point, the installed helix / p4 packages got caught in an apt-get upgrade (they shouldn't have been, they were manual downloads & installs of .deb packages), and that put the latest 2022 version on the machine.

Turns out, the latest Perforce Server release does not work on that old machine, or maybe it's that it doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.  Either way, installing an early 2021 release worked.  And, you can - in fact - drop all the depot files from a depot backup into a new, empty depot, and it'll work.

Most baffling 5 days I've ever spent beating on a command line.